# Cannot Find Protocol Declaration for my class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

I have tried everything to correct this issue. Some other posts discussed about a possible circular inclusion of header files and to use @class declaration. I have tried this, to no avail. My code cannot find the protocol declaration for my MapPreferencesDelegate. I would appreciate any help. I have attached screen shots of my code below!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's **UITableViewDataSource** NOT **UITableViewDataSourcem**

Comment: Where is the `MapPreferencesDelegate` declared? You need to import this class.

Comment: Could be he actually has a dataSourcem. If so, that's a very bad name for a protocol.

Comment: @CrimsonChris it was obviously a typo

Comment: Didn't want to assume.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined your protocol *after* you're using it in your class, you need to forward-declare it.  eg:

```
@protocol MyProtocol;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MyProtocol>

// etc...

@end

@protocol MyProtocol

- (void)aMethod;

@end
```